# Print items in *args

Tags: python

I am implementing decorators and am trying to get the output

- "Hi John"
- "Hi Tom"
- "Hi John"
- "Hi Tom"

Please can someone explain why the `.format(i for i in args)` doesn't iterate through `John` and `Tom` but instead prints the location of the variables `args`

```
def doDouble (func):
    def wrapper_doDouble (*args):
        func(*args)
        func(*args)
    return wrapper_doDouble

@doDouble
def functionToPrint(*args):
    print ("Hi {}".format(i for i in args))

functionToPrint("John", "Tom")
```

This is my current output:

```
Hi <generator object functionToPrint.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x03CEFD80>
Hi <generator object functionToPrint.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x03CDA1B0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inline for loop is in slightly the wrong place.  You want to call `Hi` format repeatedly, not pass a list into `Hi`.  Since that will generate multiple values you need to `join` them back together.

```
def doDouble (func):
    def wrapper_doDouble (*args):
        func(*args)
        func(*args)
    return wrapper_doDouble

@doDouble
def functionToPrint(*args):
    print ("\n".join("Hi {}".format(i) for i in args))

functionToPrint("John", "Tom")
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not in the decorator. It is in the `format`.

```
 "hi {}".format("john", "tom")
```

will only print "john", since you only use the first argument in your formatted string. Replace it with eg

```
print ("\n".join(len(args) *["Hi {}"])).format(*args))
```

Comment: This would mean I have to know the number of arguments being passed in. I thought the point of *args was that I don't always know this. Is it possible to set up on a single line of code to accept any number of arguments using .format? I am trying to use the for loop to change the value of i each time as you can see